# Copying one array to another array from a specific index in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to copy one array to another.

What I am trying to do is copy the content of Array1 to Array2. But the Array2 content should have contents from a particular index. For example:

Array1 have 100 elements ie. index from 0 to 99. In Array2 I want to copy say, elements from index 25 to last element(ie. 99).

How can I do it. I try searching the problem but did not get the solution.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

If you have this array:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and you want to obtain a copy from the 3rd element up to the end:

```
var y = x[2..<x.count]
```

`y` will contain `[3, 4, 5]`

Note that arrays are value types, so they are copied by value - every time you assign an array to another variable (or pass to a function), a copy of it is actually assigned/passed. So you don't have to do anything more to obtain a copy.

Comment: if the start index is a variable

Comment: just use the variable instead of the literal: `var index = 2; var y = x[index..<x.count]`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Range` subscription like this:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4, .....]
let sliced = array[25...99]
```

Note that, type of `sliced` here is `Slice<Int>`, it has almost the same interface as `Array`, so you can use that as `Array` as is.

If you do want real `Array`, do `Array(array[25...99])`